# Как прочесть строку из базы данных и подменить значения?

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite

нужно получить с таблицы Group строку с данными и подменить их например [3]-[2] первое значения в квадратных скобках значит что нужно взять с таблицы List 3 строку с данными 'трактор' и другое значение с таблицы Brand 'джон дир' и эти значение поместить в две разные переменные

трактор - джон дир

машина - ауди

мотоцикл - дукати

структура БД:

```
List
    |---------|----------| 
    | list_id |  title   |
    |---------|----------|
    |    1    |  машина  |
    |---------|----------|
    |    2    | мотоцикл |
    |---------|----------|
    |    3    | трактор  |
    |---------|----------|

Brand
    |---------|----------| 
    |brand_id |  title   |
    |---------|----------|
    |    1    |  ауди    |
    |---------|----------|
    |    2    | джон дир |
    |---------|----------|
    |    3    |  дукати  |
    |---------|----------|


Group
    |----------|-------------------| 
    | Group_id |       text        |
    |----------|-------------------|
    |    1     | [4]-[23],         |
    |          | [9]-[3]           |
    |----------|-------------------|
    |    2     | [2]-[37],         |
    |          | [8]-[41],         |
    |          | [11]-[24],        |
    |          | [2]-[15]          |
    |----------|-------------------|
```

Код

```
def my_db():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite')
    c = conn.cursor()

    c.execute('SELECT * FROM List WHERE list_id = 1')
    row = c.fetchone()

    # закрываем соединение с базой
    c.close()
    conn.close()

    return row
```

Comment: ничего не понятно без структур таблиц. но видимо, вы спрашиваете о `join`

Comment: структура складывается с двух таблиц List и Brand

Comment: при такой ужасной структуре поля text, наверное, можно написать запрос, но проще разобрать его в языке программирования, составить список id, получить из базы по критерию where id in(список id) и сделать подстановку

Comment: пожалуйста, покажите на примеры кода

Comment: дело в том, что на питоне не умею. логику могу рассказать, а вот написать код - слабо :) Может. кто умеющий подскажет. Но код тут не часто пишут, правильно было бы вам попробовать и обратиться с проблемами

Comment: покажите на примере php

Comment: Структуру базы надо кардинально менять. Вы с ума сойдете решать такую задачу на любом языке. вот [8]-[41] - это что значит ? Взять запись с ID 8 и из той таблицы взять 41 колонку ? А что если при переливке базы порядок колонок в таблице окажется иной ?

Comment: это как так что после переливки может измениться уникальной id ?
не колонку а два id c разных таблиц

Comment: у вас в чем проблема. Прочитать из Group вы можете? Если вы не знаете как обработать поле text? я вам сейчас код на php напишу, но не знаю, насколько это вам поможет

Comment: Опишите словами в чём у вас проблема. Я вижу код в вопросе, который по ID запрашивает запись из таблицы и сохраняет её в переменной (`row`)—то есть ответ на вопрос в заголовке у вас уже есть. Если у вас сложности с тем как вытащить числа из строки вида `"[4]-[23],\n[9]-[2]"`, чтобы получить вложенный список, то спросите об этом в виде отдельного вопроса—это  не имеет никакого отношения к базам данных. Если у вас вопрос: как, имея вложенный список, вызвать код в вопросе в цикле, то поработайте с вводными руководствами, чтобы научиться циклы организовывать—попытайтесь просто значения напечатать.

Answer (score 3):

```
$text = '[2]-[37], [8]-[41],    [11]-[24],      [2]-[15]'; 

$arr = array_map(trim, explode(',',$text));
$arr = array_map(function($i) {
        $i = array_map(function ($j) { return trim($j, "[]"); }, 
                       explode('-', $i));
        return $i;
        }, $arr);

 print_r($arr);
```

в результате будет вот такой массив

```
[ [2, 37], [8, 41], [11, 24], [2, 15] ]
```

теперь собираете нулевые индексы и делаете запрос к List с where list_id in (список) и с элементами с индекс = 1 ко второй таблице. А дальше просто оформить вывод