# создать вложенный список с числами из строки (есть PHP код, нужен Python)

Tags: php, python

```
$text = '[2]-[37], [8]-[41], [11]-[24], [2]-[15]'; 

$arr = array_map(trim, explode(',',$text));
$arr = array_map(function($i) {
$i = array_map(function ($j) { return trim($j, "[]"); }, 
explode('-', $i));
return $i;
}, $arr);

print_r($arr);
```

в результате должен быть вот такой массив:

```
[ [2, 37], [8, 41], [11, 24], [2, 15] ]
```

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Как прочесть строку из базы данных и подменить значения?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/515844/23044)

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы найти все натуральные числа в строке и сгруппировать их по парам в Питоне 3:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = '[2]-[37], [8]-[41], [11]-[24], [2]-[15]'
>>> list(zip(*[map(int, re.findall('\d+', text))]*2))
[(2, 37), (8, 41), (11, 24), (2, 15)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
text = '[2]-[37], [8]-[41], [11]-[24], [2]-[15]'

def foo(text):
    return [
        [int(w.strip('[]')) for w in s.strip().split('-')] for s in text.split(',')
    ]

print(foo(text))
```